# Can I do this with cycle()?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cycle

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kc7zY/3/) code :

#### HTML

```
<div class='myDiv'>1</div>
<div class='myDiv'>2</div>
<div class='myDiv'>3</div>
<div class='myDiv' style='display:none'>4</div>
<div class='myDiv' style='display:none'>5</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.myDiv
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    border:2px solid #000000;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {

});
```

and I'd like, when I click on `MOVE`, to slide to the left the divs `myDiv`.

So, if the start is `1 2 3`, clicking on `MOVE` it must become `2 3 4`, than `3 4 5` and son on.

I'd like to do it with the `.cycle()` plugins, but I don't know if I can setup a `scroll-window` with it.

Is it possible? Or I need to implement my own jQuery/JS functions? (with `fade/slide effect`, will be an hard work).

Comment: So you want to display three images at a time, like a carousel ( http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ )?

Comment: Well... somethings like this, but the images must scroll 1-at-time...not 3 at time (this is easy with cycle())...

Comment: Set the carousel's "scroll" property to 1: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration

Comment: But the question was : can I do it with `.cycle()`? :)

Comment: To which I would reply: why use a pliers to pound in a nail?

Comment: You are right. In fact I know how cycle works.. and I'd like to use it for this kind of works...

Comment: So, can you give an example for this case?

Comment: OMG! Next/prev buttons are avaiable binding the event. That's sucks!!!!

Comment: Ciao! Ok... I've done an example with prev - next buttons ... sucks that too?

Comment: I updated my answer to have only one button like in your question!

Answer (score 2):

You can use carousel lite with ***scroll*** set to 1 ***visible*** set to 3

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#doc

Answer (score 1):

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/BxfD4/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var galW = $('#gallery').width(),
        my = $('.mydivs').length, // 3
        mD = $('.myDiv').length,  // 6
        c = 1;

    $('#slider').width(galW * my);

    function a() {
        $('#slider').animate({left: '-='+(galW/3)}, 800);
    }

    $('.btn').click(function() {
        c++;
        if(c===(mD-1)){
            $('#slider').animate({left:0}, 800);
            c=1; return;
        }
        a();
    });
});
```

**Or if you want - with PREV AND NEXT buttons:**

### [WORKING DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/Gfh5a/1/)

(You can find the basic tutorial [HERE](http://roxon.in/scripts/tutorials/NavGallery_jQuery_Tutorial_01/))

Happy coding!